# What are the downsides of using binding in order to update a JSF component?

Tags: jsf-2

Consider this xhtml piece.

```
            <p:dialog id="consumerDialog"
                      widgetVar="dealerDialog" modal="true">
                <h:panelGroup binding="#{cdContent}">

                </h:panelGroup>
            </p:dialog>

            <p:dialog id="dealerDialog"
                      widgetVar="dealerDialog" modal="true">
                <h:form>
                    <p:commandButton value="Close"
                         onclick="PF('dealerDialog').hide()" 
                         update=":#{cdContent.clientId}"/>
                </h:form>

            </p:dialog>
```

In the `dealerDialog` component is a `p:commandButton` which updates the `h:panelGroup` component inside the `consumerDialog` where the id of the updated component is obtained through binding. I sometimes do this to save pains figuring out the actual id of the target component (especially for complex views).

Are there any downsides or risks if I do it this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Are there any downsides or risks if I do it this way?*

Only if the EL variable represented in `binding`, which is in your case `#{cdContent}`, is shared by multiple components in the same view. E.g. when the given code snippet is included multiple times in the same template via `<ui:include>`, tagfile or composite. Or even when there's a managed bean on that name. It doesn't apply in your case, but it would for sure fail if the `binding` attribtue references a session scoped bean property.

There are no risks if you make absolutely sure that `#{cdContent}` is exclusively used by only one component in the entire view.

#### See also:

- [How does the 'binding' attribute work in JSF? When and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-does-the-binding-attribute-work-in-jsf-when-and-how-should-it-be-used)

Comment: I have a rather late question. Do you know what scope this variable will have? Like RequestScoped or ViewScoped. Not sure if it makes a difference though.

Comment: Technically Facelet scoped, but you can interpret it as request scoped.